# Invoking method in C++

Tags: c++, methods, variable-assignment

A question about C++ programming.

Can you do in C++ something like this:

```
Lecture le;
Carriage ca = le;
```

No casting, just writing like that. The problem is, when I am trying to invoke a method which belongs to Lecture class the methods is underlined in red.

```
ca.runIt();
```

I am not quite sure if I understood the specification of my task, but there is given this snippet of code. Best regards

Comment: This question is incredibly vague. To start with, what are the definitions of the `Lecture` and `Carriage` types?

Comment: Can you "do something like this"? Yes. Does it do what you think it does? Probably not.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail the "specification of my task"? Perhaps there is some aspect of your problem that we aren't understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you do in C++ something like this:

Yes.

```
struct Lecture {
};
struct Carriage {
  Carriage(const Lecture&) {
  }
  void runIt() {
  }
};

int main() {
  Lecture le;
  Carriage ca = le;
  ca.runIt();
}
```

> The problem is, when I am trying to invoke a method which belongs to Lecture class the methods is underlined in red.

Of course. `ca` isn't a `Lecture`. `ca` is a `Carriage`. You can only invoke `Carriage` methods on `ca`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down, from the general case to the most specific.

If you have some arbitrary class `A` and some other arbitrary class `B`, the statement:

```
A a;
B b = a;
```

is *generally* not going to work. It will *certainly* not work by itself; you have to put effort into making it work.

So now, let's get specific. If `B` is a class derived from `A`, then it will *also* not work. If `A` is derived from `B`, it will *still* not work.

Why? Because `A a` defines an object, not a reference. It creates a value. `B b = a;` is an attempt to store the value `a` into a new value `b`. You cannot do that.

If `A` is derived from `B` (`B` is the base class), you *can* do this:

```
A a;
B &b = a;
```

That's legal C++, and it's meaningful too. `b` now refers to *part* of `a`. Specifically, the part of `a` that is the base class.

Note that the reverse does not work. If `A` were the base class, C++ would raise an error.

Now, there is one way to make the general statement work.

```
A a;
B b = a;
```

If you want this to be reasonable for a *specific* class `B`, then `B` must be defined as follows:

```
class B ... //Whatever base classes you want.
{
public:
  B(const A &a);
};
```

The constructor that takes a `const A &` is a conversion constructor. It's job is to create a `B` object using data from an `a` object. Because this conversion constructor was declared *without* the `explicit` keyword, then it can be used for implicit conversions like `B b = a;` If it were declared *with* the `explicit` keyword, you would have to explicitly convert it: `B b = B(a);`.

Having a conversion constructor on a class means that any instance of `A` can be converted into a `B`. So you can pass `A` to a function that takes a `B` (either by value or by `const&`. *Not* by reference) without having to do an explicit conversion.

Note that conversion constructing an object does *not* allow you to call functions from `A` on the object `B`. You can only call functions on `B` which `B` defines or are defined by one of `B`'s base classes.

Comment: Thank you people for so many answers. I just discovered that there was a mistake in the contents of the source file. Instead of Carriage there supposed to be a Lecture class. By the way, inheritance is not used in this program.